# How to apply a transparent texture

Tags: texturing, transparency

I have a transparent texture and I can't figure out how to apply that transparency to the object.

[image: example as used]

As you can see, the texture in the bottom right is transparent in places and solid in others.
But in render view the texture is just black.

[image: example with white background]

You can see it better here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
Where Alpha = black = 0, the Transparent shader is used ; when alpha = white = 1, the Diffuse is used ; for intermediate value, they are mixed.